# Can I force a default special member function to be noexcept?

Tags: c++, c++11, noexcept

The following structure fails to compile under C++11 due to the fact that I have declared the move assignment operator as `noexcept`:

```
struct foo
{
  std::vector<int> data;
  foo& operator=(foo&&) noexcept = default;
};
```

The default move assignment operator generated by the compiler is `noexcept(false)` due to the fact that `std::vector<int>`'s move assignment is also `noexcept(false)`.  This in turn is due to the fact that the default allocator has `std::allocator_traits<T>:: propagate_on_container_move_assignment` set to `std::false_type`.  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332772/why-arent-container-move-assignment-operators-noexcept).

I believe this has been fixed in C++14 (see [library defect 2103](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2103)).

My question is, is there a way for me to force `noexcept` upon the default move assignment assignment operator without having to define it myself?

If this is not possible, is there a way I can trick the `std::vector<int>` into being `noexcept` move assignable so that `noexcept(true)` is passed through to my struct?

Comment: Is it okay if `data` is a `std::vector<int, A>` where `A` is not the default `std::allocator<int>`?

Comment: I'm looking to keep code complexity at a minimum.  I'd expect that using a custom allocator is harder for other coders to understand than a simple non-default move assignment operator.

Comment: That said, if the `A` in `std::vector<int, A>` is a simple inline wrapper for the default allocator it might work...

Comment: What is suppose to happen if the move operation on your data throws?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I believe this has been fixed in C++14 (see library defect 2103).

As a DR that fix should be considered a correction to C++11 and so some C++11 implementations will have already fixed it.

> My question is, is there a way for me to force `noexcept` upon the default move assignment assignment operator without having to define it myself?

For the defaulted move assignment operator to be `noexcept` you need to make its sub-objects have `noexcept` move assignment operators.

The most obvious portable way I can think of is to use a wrapper around `std::vector` which forces the move to be `noexcept`

```
template<typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T>>
  struct Vector : std::vector<T, A>
  {
    using vector::vector;

    Vector& operator=(Vector&& v) noexcept
    {
      static_cast<std::vector<T,A>&>(*this) = std::move(v);
      return *this;
    }
    Vector& operator=(const Vector&) = default;
  };
```

Another similar option is to define your own allocator type with the DR 2013 fix and use that:

```
template<typename T>
  struct Allocator : std::allocator<T>
  {
    Allocator() = default;
    template<typename U> Allocator(const Allocator<U>&) { }
    using propagate_on_container_move_assignment  = true_type;
    template<typename U> struct rebind { using other = Allocator<U>; };
  };

template<typename T>
  using Vector = std::vector<T, Allocator<T>>;
```

Another option is to use a standard library implementation such as GCC's which implements the resolution to DR 2013 and also makes `std::vector`'s move assignment operator `noexcept` for other allocator types when it is known that all allocator instances compare equal.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can force anything, but you may wrap it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct Wrap
{
    public:
    Wrap() noexcept
    {
        new (m_value) T;
    }

    Wrap(const Wrap& other) noexcept
    {
        new (m_value) T(std::move(other.value()));
    }

    Wrap(Wrap&& other) noexcept
    {
        std::swap(value(), other.value());
    }


    Wrap(const T& other) noexcept
    {
        new (m_value) T(std::move(other));
    }

    Wrap(T&& other) noexcept
    {
        new (m_value) T(std::move(other));
    }

    ~Wrap() noexcept
    {
        value().~T();
    }

    Wrap& operator = (const Wrap& other) noexcept
    {
        value() = other.value();
        return *this;
    }

    Wrap& operator = (Wrap&& other) noexcept
    {
        value() = std::move(other.value());
        return *this;
    }

    Wrap& operator = (const T& other) noexcept
    {
        value() = other;
        return *this;
    }

    Wrap& operator = (T&& other) noexcept
    {
        value() = std::move(other);
        return *this;
    }

    T& value() noexcept { return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_value); }
    const T& value() const noexcept { return *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(m_value); }
    operator T& () noexcept { return value(); }
    operator const T& () const noexcept { return value(); }

    private:
    typename std::aligned_storage <sizeof(T), std::alignment_of<T>::value>::type m_value[1];
};


struct Foo
{
    public:
    Foo& operator = (Foo&&)  noexcept = default;

    std::vector<int>& data() noexcept { return m_data; }
    const std::vector<int>& data() const noexcept { return m_data; }

    private:
    Wrap<std::vector<int>> m_data;
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.data().push_back(1);
    Foo boo;
    boo = std::move(foo);
    // 01
    std::cout << foo.data().size() << boo.data().size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

(Thanks Jonathan Wakely)

Comment: That type is not copyable, you need copy ctor and assignment op. Also, you can use `std::aligned_storage<T>::type` instead of a char array.