# Fast move assignment with Howard Hinnant's short_alloc

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11, move-semantics, allocator

I am using Howard Hinnant's nice little arena-based allocator, [short_alloc](http://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html).

It struck me that move-assigning from a vector, which has outgrown its arena and is thus allocated on heap, could be done using the usual, fast move-assignment (i.e., grabbing the target's resources). However, this is not the case:

```
typedef arena<16>                     arena_type;
typedef short_alloc<int, 16>          alloc_type;
typedef std::vector<int, alloc_type>  vec_type;

arena_type arena1, arena2;
vec_type vec1(alloc_type(arena1)), vec2(alloc_type(arena2));
vec1.resize(100);

void* data = vec1.data();
vec2 = std::move(vec1);
assert(vec2.data() == data);  // fails
```

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12334918/728847), this is due to the vector's move assignment operator comparing the two allocators (note that `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` is `std::false_type`). Since the two allocators don't compare equal (because they have different arenas), the target vector needs to allocate memory and move the values one by one.

The desired behaviour is achieved by changing the equality operator to

```
template <class T1, size_t N1, class T2, size_t N2>
bool operator==(const short_alloc<T1, N1>& x, const short_alloc<T2, N2>& y) noexcept
{
    return N1 == N2 && (&x.a_ == &y.a_ || y.a_.on_heap());
}
```

where `on_heap()` checks if the allocator is not using its arena.

This solution looks rather hackish (note for example that equality is not symmetric), can/will I shoot myself in the foot by doing this? Is there a elegant solution?

Comment: couldn't this return true on different value types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two different `arena` objects may have different lifetime. Two different `short_alloc` objects that depend on different `arena` objects manage memory with different lifetime. As a result, two `std::vector` objects with different short_alloc objects can't simply move pointers between them.

Your hack won't work, since it is the pointer that is allocated either from the `arena` or by `new[]`. Your hack assumes that the allocator becomes a heap allocator for big vectors, but this is not the case. This is not something that an allocator knows without inspecting the requested size or the freed pointer.

The correct solution is to replace the allocator object with the move operator. To do that, `short_alloc` should define:

```
   using propagate_on_container_move_assignment = std::true_type;
private:
   arena_type * a_;  // <--- instead of reference
public:
   short_alloc(const short_alloc&) = default;
   // !!! Don't delete the move assignment !!!
   // short_alloc& operator=(const short_alloc&) = delete;
```

This will make the move operator work as expected. It will start using the other arena after the move.

---

In general, such allocation techniques are very dangerous and should be rarely used, due to their high risk of memory-related bugs. For example, if one is to return a vector from a function, there is a high risk for it to refer to an `arena` on a scope that is about to be exited.

With my proposed change, the risk factor is slightly higher. The problem of the `arena` going out-of-scope now also goes to pass-by-reference vectors. The problem of the `arena` going out-of-scope also exists when the `arena` is defined in an inner block.

This behavior of the other `arena` going out of scope can surprise a programmer, and introduce bugs. That's why I am not a fan of this solution. However, sometimes one is willing to write dangerous code in time-critical sections (after profiling and analyzing).

---

As the question suggests, it is possible to mark a `short_alloc` allocator as a *heap* allocator when applicable. It can be marked this way right after the first allocation that uses `new[]`. This will work well with `std::vector`, since it holds only one chunk of memory between method calls. Despite working with `std::vector`, it breaks with most other containers, because most of them use nodes, such as `std::map` and `std::unordered_set`.

The problem is that some of the nodes come from the `arena` and some from the heap. With the suggested `operator==` that returns `true` if `new[]` is used, a move from `std::map` will make some nodes from an unrelated arena move the the target `std::map`. Very unexpected, and a bad idea. This will result in a `std::map` object that contains nodes from its own `arena` and from an unrelated `arena`. The nodes of the unrelated `arena` will never be freed by `std::map`. These bad nodes will be freed only when their allocating `arena` dies.

The technique proposed in the question is completely broken. It results with inconsistent allocations in surprising ways for almost anything but `std::vector`. I will strongly advise against it.