# C++ How to add queue of unique_ptr's to a vector

Tags: c++, stl, copy-constructor, unique-ptr

Simplified code:

```
#include <queue>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {};
    virtual ~Foo() {}
};

int main()
{
    std::queue<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> queue;
    auto element = std::make_unique<Foo>();
    queue.push(std::move(element));
    std::vector<std::queue<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>> vector;
    // Error 1
    vector.push_back(queue); 
    // Error 2
    vector.push_back(std::move(queue));
    // Error 3
    vector.push_back({});
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

> 'std::unique_ptr>::unique_ptr(const
>   std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to
>   reference a deleted function

Obviously copying c~tor of unique_ptr is removed but I'm not trying to copy it. Am I?

Comment: Yes, `push_back` makes a copy.  To create an object in place, use `emplace_back`.

Comment: It works if `std::queue` is replaced by `std::vector`; doesn't work with the default queue underlier of `std::deque`.  But it does work fine to `move` a `deque` that isn't in a vector. Weird

Comment: @M.M Yes, you can move a `deque` that isn't in a `vector`. The operation will not be `noexcept` however. `vector` just doesn't like potentially throwing moves (see aschepler's answer for details).

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit tricky.  All `std::vector<T>` functions that can increase the size of the vector have to do it in an exception-safe way if either of these two things are true:

- `T` has a move constructor that guarantees it will never throw any exceptions; or,
- `T` has a copy constructor.

So in most implementations, if `T` has a move constructor declared `nothrow` or equivalent, `vector` will use the move constructor of `T` for those operations.  If not, and `T` has a copy constructor, `vector` will use the copy constructor, even if `T` has a move constructor.

And the problem here is that `std::queue` always declares it has a copy constructor, even if that copy constructor can't actually be instantiated, and always declares it has a move constructor that might throw, even if the container member's move constructor guarantees it won't throw.

The Standard specifies these in [queue.defn] as:

```
namespace std {
  template<class T, class Container = deque<T>>
  class queue {
    // ...
  public:
    explicit queue(const Container&);
    explicit queue(Container&& = Container());
    // ...
  };
}
```

This class template definition could be improved in a couple of ways to be more "SFINAE-friendly" and avoid issues like the one you ran into.  (Maybe somebody could check for other classes with similar issues and submit a proposal to the Library Working Group.)

1. Change the move constructor to promise not to throw if the `Container` type makes the same promise, typically done with language like:

   ```
   explicit queue(Container&& rhs = Container()) nothrow(see below);
   ```

   *Remarks:* The expression inside `noexcept` is equivalent to `is_­nothrow_­move_­constructible_­v<Container>`.
2. Change the copy constructor to be deleted if the `Container` type is not copyable, typically done with language like:

   ```
   explicit queue(const Container&);
   ```

   *Remarks:* This constructor shall be defined as deleted unless `is_­copy_­constructible_­v<Container>` is `true`.

Comment: I found the same issue with using `deque` directly

Comment: @M.M Not sure what you mean. Can you link to an example?

Comment: @M.M Okay, yeah. The move constructor of `queue` is also not declared `noexcept`. Which is more of a surprise, since it ought to be possible to move a `deque` no matter what the element type is, and this is different from `vector` for no obvious reason.

Comment: I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12334918/1505939) talking about it... allocator traits are involved, which explains why I've been unable to reproduce the problem with a test non-nothrow_move_constructible class (instead of `deque`)

Comment: [this thread](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2017-08/msg00079.html) suggests some rationale for `deque` not being nothrow-movable

Comment: The code builds OK with container `queue< unique_ptr<Foo>, vector<unique_ptr<Foo>> >`, so perhaps `deque` is the underlying issue and `queue` itself is OK

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm ok with changing queue container type from deque to vector. Saying that I'm changing my outer container to be std::vector<std::queue<std::unique_ptr<Foo>, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>>> vector;